# JSON Element isJsonNull true on {} values

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have the following JSON response and I am using GSON google Java lib 2.3.1 for parsing JSON objects.

```
{
    "ClubName": "Test 3 Day",
    "Date": {},
    "CurrentSeqNo": {},
    "Logo": "/online/devadehil/club.png",
    "IsDateDisplayed": "false",
    "Secured": "false"    
}
```

I am using Java code as follows:

```
JsonElement elem = response.get("Date");
 if(!elem.isJsonNull()) //set to true
  elem.getAsString(); // throws exception here
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
```

Comment: Yes, but is there anyway, on client side we can handle that value??

Comment: Could you add full stack trace?

Comment: hey @KonradKrakowiak It's failing on this method.   at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)

Comment: ok, but I asked about your stacktrace 
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject` is not enough.

Comment: Take a look on my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had exception because you call `getAsString()` method on `JsonObject` instance. Default implementation of this method is:

```
public String getAsString() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

and it is override only on `JsonArray` and `JsonPrimitive` class.

**You cannot use this method for JsonObject instance.**

You can edit condition in your code like this : `if(!elem.isJsonNull() && !elem.isJsonObject())`

Comment: Thanks, It fixes the problem, but It would be good, if elem.isJSONNull return null, if it has no value. for example, date: {}

Comment: I am glad that I could help you.